# Why does "Git help <command>" not launch html help in my browser, like it says it should?

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, html-help

I am really enjoying my time with git.

I'm operating on 2 machines with what I thought were pretty similar setups

**On my Laptop**

When I type "Git help `SomeCommand`" from the CLI, my laptop launches the html help in my browser and I am free to read up on whatever help element I asked about.

**On my Desktop**

The CLI responds as if is is going to do the same, but no browser is switched to and no help is launched

**What can I do to get my help back on my desktop?**

Note: I'm running the bash shell through console2, but this problem appears to affect the default bash shell run via the context menu in explorer just as much.

Comment: Does `git help <cmd>` output `Launching default browser to display HTML ...` at least?

Comment: What is your default browser set to?

Comment: Stab in the dark: I've always done git <cmd> --help. Does that work?

Comment: Ok ... you're not going to believe this. but yes that worked... What's more the normal way now works. Go figure?

Comment: @Joshua FWIW default browser is FF4 on both machines.

Comment: @Rory, just to clarify, using `git <cmd> --help` worked, but After that, `git help <cmd>` works too?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26717142/127465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this bug went away when I upgraded to the latest version of msysgit (1.7.6 from 1.7.3)

Answer (score 8):

I just recently had the same problem, browser wouldn't launch. 
I'm running Git 1.9.2.msysgit.0 on Windows 8.1. Default browser - Chrome.

None of the solutions above worked for me. But I simply went to the html file in the explorer, and double-clicked it. Windows then asked me what app to use to open it, and I chose chrome.

Now usual git commands work and open the help html files in Chrome.

Comment: So in other words, you didn't have any default application for HTML files, right? It should ask you to select an application to open the specified file type automatically. Anyway, it's enough to just open _Control panel_ > _Default Programs_ > _Associate a file type or protocol with a program_ > find `.html` and assign any program you want to use to open such file type.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [msysgit bug report 445](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=445):

> Git has it's own tool called "`git web--browse`" that invokes the web-browser.
>
> Set the environment `GIT_TRACE` to 1 to see what processes are started, and with what 
>   command-lines.

So that can help debugging the issue.

A temporary workaround (which might not be effective in your case) was:

> As temporary workaround one can rename all `git-<command>.html` to `git<command>.html` in his `<Git>\doc\git\html` directory.

The `git <cmd> --help` suggested by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275354/andy) seems to have helped though, and must have "reset" something.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem currently, and the `git <cmd> --help` technique doesn't fix it.

I have however found that doing

`git help -w <cmd>`

Will actually open the help file in the browser, so this is a useful workaround.

Comment: Note, I've tried setting `git config --global help.format html` to no avail.

This is with git 1.7.11 installed from the developer full install, worked with git 1.7.8 before I upgraded (also from the developer full install).

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a web browser to be used to open Git's help files independently of the system's default program assigned to open `.html` files.

To **check if it's set** and to what value, simply run:

```
git config web.browser
```

To **set it globally** for all repositories, for example to `chrome`, run:

```
git config --global web.browser chrome
```

You can also **set it per-repository**, in that case run it inside a repository and without the `--global` parameter:

```
git config web.browser chrome
```

It works automatically if the specified browser's executable is in `PATH`. If it's not, you may set it manually:

```
git config browser.<name>.path <path-to-browser-executable>
```

...so for Chrome browser, it may look like the following:

```
git config browser.chrome.path "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

See the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-web--browse.html) for details.

Comment: I don't like this solution, because it fiddles with browser names and maybe even paths. I just used `git config --global help.format html` to set my help format. `git help` then uses my default browser.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (browser wouldn't open), then I realized it's probably because our laptops at work are "least privileged access", meaning we're logged into our Windows systems as standard users.  But for development work, including the command window I'm doing git commands from, I'm running as a different user who has local admin privileges.  So it actually *was* opening the Chrome browser, just not in my "logged in" desktop session where I could see it.

To work around this, I ran another copy of Chrome *as that user* (by Shift-Right clicking on Chrome.exe and running it as the same privileged user that my command prompt is running as).  Once that instance of Chrome was running on my desktop, I returned to the command prompt and re-ran the "git help " and it properly launched a new tab in that instance of the browser that was running as the same user my command prompt was.

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark: I've always done `git <cmd> --help`.  Does that work?

edit: For future reference.  This appears to be what fixed the OP's problem. Running `git <cmd> --help` seemed to have cleared out something so that it works as specified now.  If only I knew the how/why of it...

Comment: Oops, sorry about that I appeared to accept the wrong answer. Corrected :)

Comment: Not that it was a very good answer. I just threw a dart into the night and it hit something. Too bad I don't even know what I hit...

Comment: So it's happened again and now this tip doesn't appear to help :(

Answer (score 0):

**This set up is current, working and the convention.**

It's most likely because you are using the default Git that comes with MacOS called Apple Git which is outdated.

run `git --version` and check against the [Git](https://git-scm.com) website.

Install Git using `brew install git`.

To make sure Homebrew installs take precedence over MacOS installs add the usr/local/bin path to your .zshrc or .bash_profile. `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. (*Btw, you should use this path also for using Python 3 instead of MacOS Python 2.7 and many other applications).

To make sure all of this is activated do `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`. Or simply restart Terminal.

Test it. `git help -w commit`. A browser window will open.