# Git fatal: failed to launch browser

Tags: git, path

I am trying to use Git's inbuilt help commands however I always get the message

```
$ git help status
Launching default browser to display HTML ...
fatal: failed to launch browser for C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/doc/git/html//git-status.html
```

I suspect it is the path to the help files being wrong which is causing the problem the actual pat is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\doc\git\html`). How would I go about correcting this issue? Or is it another problem that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Side note: You get exactly the same error message when you mistype the command you seek help for. Try `git help statuss` or `git help mrege` ...

Answer (score 0):

That path should be fine, the slashes will sort themselves out.

I'm guessing you don't have an html browser set up for git. See [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-web--browse.html) for relevant documentation.

I'd suggest to put the *full path* to your browser's executable in the `web.browser` configuration variable as shown in the documentation. The Unix-y way of having everything in PATH does not quite translate to Windows.

Comment: have inputted both`$git config --global web.browser chrome` and `$ git config --global browser.chrome.path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome
\Application\chrome.exe'` neither seem to have made a difference as I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem was a repeating backslash in the path.
In the latest version (git version 2.5.0.windows.1) this problem is fixed.
However, a similar problem remains - when the path contains non-ASCII symbols (user Владик):

```
C:\Users\Владик>git help -w add
Launching default browser to display HTML ...
fatal: failed to launch browser for C:\Users\Владик\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\mingw32/share/doc/git-doc/git-add.html
```

The help command works fine with ASCII path, for example when user = "user1"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the config values for `web.browser` or `browser.<tool>.path` didn't work for me.

What solved the problem on Windows is to find (or create) a .html file, right click > open with > choose default program, and select the browser you want (and make sure you check the 'always use the selected program to open this kind of file' checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out that if you have a typo in your command or there is no help page you will get the same error.

This comes from how it tries to resolve the command.